# catkin_make error in Hydro

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-hydro, build, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the step by step instructions on the gazebo tutorials and am somewhat dissapointed by this error in the final step (catkin_make):

Using Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Hydro:

```
[ 97%] Built target gazebo_ros_paths_plugin
[ 98%] Building CXX object gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeFiles/default_robot_hw_sim.dir/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp.o
[100%] Built target gazebo_ros_control
/home/leorm/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:279:3: error: ‘EffortJointSaturationInterface’ in namespace ‘joint_limits_interface’ does not name a type
/home/leorm/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo_ros_control::DefaultRobotHWSim::writeSim(ros::Time, ros::Duration)’:
/home/leorm/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:210:5: error: ‘ej_sat_interface_’ was not declared in this scope
/home/leorm/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp: In member function ‘void gazebo_ros_control::DefaultRobotHWSim::registerEffortJointLimits(const string&, const hardware_interface::JointHandle&, const ros::NodeHandle&, const urdf::Model*)’:
/home/leorm/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:267:15: error: ‘EffortJointSaturationHandle’ in namespace ‘joint_limits_interface’ does not name a type
/home/leorm/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:268:9: error: ‘ej_sat_interface_’ was not declared in this scope
/home/leorm/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:268:42: error: ‘sat_handle’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeFiles/default_robot_hw_sim.dir/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeFiles/default_robot_hw_sim.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83681/catkin_make-error-in-hydro/) by [leoRoss123](https://answers.ros.org/users/7131/leoross123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-26**:
This looks like a build error in `gazebo_ros_control` which is in the `gazebo_ros_pkgs` repository, please file a ticket against their repository:

https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues

**Comment by [kaizadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/7886/kaizadr/) on 2013-10-18**:
I am getting this same exact error with 12.04, ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9 (installed from source). But I can still roslaunch gazebo and see all the ros topics and services. Have you come across any solutions?

**Comment by [jmdepaco](https://answers.ros.org/users/7961/jmdepaco/) on 2013-10-21**:
I am also getting the same error with 12.04, ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9.

**Comment by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on 2014-02-06**:
Has anyone figured out why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hydro does not support Ubuntu 10.04. You should either use a newer Ubuntu version or stick with an older ROS distribution (see http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-apr-2013).

Anyway the error message you have posted just shows a compile error due to missing declarations. But without further information what exact code (repos + branches) you have checked out in the workspace there is no way to tell if the set of packages should actually work together or if you have wrong versions checked out.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0